# Issue in DocuSign web hook response with php

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API. To stay up-to-date I have used the DocuSign web hook system.

But sometimes my web hook server has an error:

> Error: The request was aborted. The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept (check) the best answers to your questions. Please also upvote all useful answers that you read on StackOverflow--including answers to questions by others. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're including the documents in the notification message payload, then you can get this error message when the size of the notification message exceeds the PHP maximum POST message size.

The best, and recommended solution, is to **not** include documents in the notification message. Instead, your app can request the documents by using the API.

Or you can increase the PHP maximum POST message size. Use Google to find out how.

Comment: Yes, You are right I am including document into notification let me remove and check Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using DocuSign Connect. There are logs that you can check for the DocuSign Connect. If you go to the Admin panel, you can see these logs that should provide more information.
To me, it seems like a networking issue, but I'm not sure. Make sure to use TLS 1.1 or above and that you have a valid SSL certificate on your server.

More info:

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Connect/